# Please don't send camera questions not about photography to Photography Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, comments, scope, migration, site-crossover

The [Photography Stack Exchange](https://photo.stackexchange.com/) site is about the art and science of photography, which is the making of images with light.

Many people want to use consumer cameras as sensors and measuring devices, which seems reasonable because the are ubiquitous and cheap. But because they are made for photography, they're not really geared for this kind of thing. Answering questions about how a consumer camera is not really working well for machine vision or scientific analysis is repetitive and tedious. And it's not *really* any more on topic than someone asking

> I want to weigh a bag of rice and I don't have a set of weights, so can someone tell me how heavy the Canon 5D is?

or

> I have a bunch of nails and need to hang up some pictures. Which lens is best for hammering them in?

Sure, those are about about camera gear, but it's not about photography. The site isn't https://camera-gear.stackexchange.com/.

Additionally, these are usually one-off questions, or a series of questions around the non-photographic use case. They don't help build a community of practice around *actual photography*.

Perhaps there is room for a site about computer vision where these kind of things would be on topic. But if there's a question about image processing or measuring things from image metadata or anything like that, please don't send the questioner to Photography.SE. That just makes everyone frustrated.

Comment: Can you provide the links of the migrated posts?

Comment: If you don't want to "name and shame" then raise a flag against the post. I've looked through recent migrations and I can't find anything to Photography.

Comment: This is prompted by https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/105720/camera-image-in-pixel-to-real-image-in-meters-size-relation, where the question-asker says "I was redirected here from stack overflow" — I presume it was a "helpful" suggestion in comment or a closed-off-topic reason.

Comment: Ah yes. I wish people wouldn't leave those. Unfortunately they used an unregistered account on Photography so I can't track them back to SO.

Comment: @ChrisF https://stackoverflow.com/q/55029990/2301450

Comment: I deleted the question on here with a comment that it's cross-posted. ChrisF deleted the comment recommending the photo se site.

Comment: Ah, the classic [“please stop using our site as your toilet bowl”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73382/please-stop-using-softwareengineering-se-as-your-toilet-bowl) plea. I guess it was inevitable. I wish there was more we could do to stop this. If you see any comments suggesting asking there, please flag them.

Comment: Sorry, our septic tank is full. There's bound to be overflow.

Comment: It would be great if people would just not recommend other SE sites for anything unless they're actually familiar enough with the other site to know what's on topic there. It's really even worse than answering when you have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: I'm confused, the post in question appears to be ontopic to your site given the tags they've managed to find. If you don't want these kinds of questions, i'm not sure why you have an image processing tag. I'd hardly blame the user for asking that question, even without being directed there. Your own help center doesn't really outline these situations either. Your own answer to the question links to another, apparently acceptable, very similar question on your site, and you hint towards there being "zillions of other questions on the same topic".  I'd hardly call the migration unwarranted.

Comment: @mattdm You're a site about the art and science of photography but that doesn't include how the area of a plane captured at a known distance in a photograph can be calculated from the measurements of the lens and aperture and stuff? I know nothing about cameras, but that looks to me like a clear, interesting, widely applicable question about the science of photography. What am I missing?

Comment: @opa The question asked doesn't appear to be about image processing (as defined by the tag wiki.) It does appear to be at least roughly about optics, though. Optics appears to be the only tag on that question that really should be there. Honestly, the 'physics' and 'camera' tags seem like they're probably kind of useless on that site. I can certainly see the argument that the asker of that question didn't do much (or any) research before asking it, but I tend to agree that it does seem like it should be on-topic for a photography Q&A.

Comment: Are these questions coming from Stack Overflow, or different SE sites? I have a hard time believing our mods would migrate stuff like the examples you've named before they were closed and downvoted to oblivion on Stack Overflow

Comment: @ErikA That particular one wasn't actually migrated. Someone commented on SO recommending asking on Photography rather than the question actually being migrated there.

Comment: @reirab Ah, that's business as usual. Site recommendations in comments on Stack Overflow to sites the person recommending isn't active should be taken with _very_ large servings of salt.

Comment: The comments from opa and Mark Amery are spot on.  I couldn't find anything in your help center that indicates this is not on-topic; and there is a [well-received question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/23414/can-we-measure-size-of-an-object-using-exif-data-from-a-photo?noredirect=1&lq=1) with some good answers that would make an excellent dupe.  In any case, this is not a problem for Stack Overflow to solve - *especially* since it was not the result of a migration.

Comment: @mattdm If you believe the question in question is not a great fit for the site, why did you answer it?

Comment: I was confused by the site's scope as well, if it wasn't for some users in the chat room of photography.SE I would still think that scientific / industrial / machine vision questions were welcome; I recommend adding something to your [don't ask](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) page very clearly explaining this; it is explained in [your meta](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5590/50370) but meta topics are rather poorly indexed by Google from my experience whereas [rather scientific posts](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/30984/50370) on photography.SE are easy to find.

Comment: ... It seems like the scope of your site is "You can ask about the science of optics and anything related to how a camera works as long as the picture is an end in itself.", maybe a bullet point like that would suffice. I have to agree with @opa that having an [image-processing](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-processing) is confusing and you may want to call it something more like "image-enhancement" so that perhaps it could cover topics like aesthetic filters like blur without including pattern recognition algorithms, edge detection, blob detection, etc...

Comment: You may be interested in befriending [Duga](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/51786/duga), it's how we're dealing with these issues over on CR. [We even have a guide for SO users too](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5777).

Comment: I'm confused by the above negativity about suggesting other SE's, e.g. SE.Photography, in comments beneath a question that may seem on-topic at those other SE's.  Elsewhere, such comments are generally regarded as constructive and actively encouraged by the community.

Comment: Speaking of which, the closed question may fit on SE.Physics, tagged with [optics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optics).  Though ideally with some generalization, where we'd have the numbers replaced by variables, to make it a bit more general.

Comment: @Nat Such comments are *strongly* discouraged unless they're being left by a user who is an active, experienced member on the site where they're suggesting the question be asked. In the majority of cases, that is not the case, and the advice is terribly, horribly wrong. It steers the asker in the wrong direction, they ask the question on yet another site where it is unwelcome, and their overall experience is profoundly negative. Not to mention it requires additional clean-up effort by another group of moderators.

Comment: @CodyGray It sounds like you're speaking from experience, though it's still hard to imagine.  I mean, usually, it's not too hard to guess that a question about electronics might go to SE.Electronics, or quantum computing might go to SE.QuantumComputing, etc..  And even when that advice turns out to be incorrect, it'd seem to be a simple matter of close-votes.  I could see this being undesirable if references tended to result in more off-topic questions than the background rate, though are referents really so incompetent as to perform worse than non-SE-members making the same selection?

Comment: @CodyGray For example, say someone has a question, and they try to ask it here on StackExchange.  A community member recognizes that it's about academia, and then suggests that it be asked on SE.Academia.  I can see potential for error there, though wouldn't that potential for error exist if the poster elected to ask on SE.Academia without a reference?  I mean, SE.Academia's going to get off-topic questions from newbies either way, though it seems that the off-topic rate would be higher from non-recommended askers rather than recommended askers.

Comment: @CodyGray That said, I understand the concern about "_toilet questions_", where someone might recommend asking on another site when the question itself is so bad that it wouldn't be worthwhile anywhere; then that's just chucking garbage.  But the issue of referring an otherwise seemingly reasonable question based on its content seems to be another matter.

Comment: @Nat Yes, they are. Just about every one of these comments I've ever seen has been wrong. Sometimes they're wrong because the topic of the question is fundamentally off-topic for the other site, and other times they're wrong because they suggest migrating extremely low-quality questions to other  sites. If you want to discuss this in more detail, ask a new question about it. It is a very dangerous sign that you're deciding which site to suggest based solely on its name. A question "about academia" should not necessarily be migrated to [Academia.SE], and that's *precisely* the problem.

Answer (score 46):

There's no system mechanism for migrating questions from here over to Photography.SE, so there's nothing we can do at a system level to change or prevent this.

One thing you could do is have a chatroom on Photography.SE that uses a bot to monitor mentions of the Photography.SE site and posts a message in the chatroom for members to come educate users on an ad-hoc basis. The folks at CodeReview.SE [do this already](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/51786/duga) as a lot of people recommend that site for questions the CodeReview.SE community feels are inappropriate.

As for the [question that prompted this](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/105720/camera-image-in-pixel-to-real-image-in-meters-size-relation), it's sending a bit of a mixed signal here that you consider it a bad fit for your site, and yet you also answered the question. Typically, at least on Stack Overflow, if a question is off-topic or shouldn't be asked, the proper thing to do is close it/downvote it, *not* answer it; answering such questions sends the signal to readers/askers that such questions are OK even in the face of closure.

Comment: "it's sending a bit of a mixed signal here that you consider it a bad fit for your site, and yet you also answered the question" with a non-answer, btw.

Comment: @Braiam right or wrong, Photo.SE is one of the friendlier communities and, if you search through closed questions, many of them have answers. We realize that just because a question isn't a good fit, doesn't mean we can't offer up some advice to the poster, who will hopefully stick around and engage more with the community.

Comment: @Hueco I'm asserting that the "mixed signals" that Tyler sees, aren't mixed. mattdm isn't answering the question that he believe it should be closed, he's using the answer box to type a comment.

Comment: @Braiam "yes" is a valid (albeit not very useful) answer to the question "can X be used to determine Y", so the answer on Photography.SE is not a non-answer.

Comment: @TylerH "How to do X" "Yes" is not an answer. People often asks "It's X possible" when they mean "how to do X". Come on, you are a seasoned user on SE, you should know this.

Comment: @Hueco My point on the mixed message is that you are going to have a bad time trying to prevent this kind of question if you answer them (either via an answer or a comment), regardless of whether you then close them.

Comment: @Braiam I am a seasoned user, so I know to go look at what question is actually being asked. It's not "How to do X" like you suggest, but rather "can X be used to determine Y" as I said. In fact, the exact question is **Is there a way to calculate the real width and height of the image?**. This is a yes or no question. If you contain ESP, that's a nice gift, but the rest of us have to rely on what is actually asked rather than assuming OP means something *different* from what they asked.

Comment: @TylerH it doesn't take ESP to know that "is there a way to do X, given Y" has an implicit "and if yes, how?" attached, it takes a basic experience with human communication.

Comment: @mbrig You're right, ESP would allow you to actually know true things. Just making up stuff like your suggestion wouldn't be reliable enough to earn the label ESP. A good answer to that question will answer the question, and if possible, include methodology for doing it. An acceptable answer will answer the Q. But if the answer is "no", do you expect an answerer to say "and here are all the ways you can't do it"? Of course not; that's absurd. So too is demanding someone provide more information than you asked for. Understanding that takes more than basic experience with human communication.

Comment: In this case, I felt inclined to provide an answer because the questioner said they'd been sent there from Stack Overflow, which wasn't *their* fault. I agree that it sends mixed messages in general.